# Android studio 4.0 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.Received status code 403 from server: OK

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have installed Android studio in Mac when i try to create new project it is not building for Kotlin and Java both languages.

Bellow exception is for Java project.

```
Exception is:
```

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'SampleJavaApp'.
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:80)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:238)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:232)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:193)
at

Bellow exception Kotlin

```
* What went wrong:
```

A problem occurred configuring root project 'SampleApplication'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET Received status code 403 from server: OK
> Could not download tink-1.3.0-rc2.jar (com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2)
> Received status code 403 from server: OK
> Could not download protobuf-java-3.10.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET
> from server: OK
> Could not download kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.4.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.4.0)
> > Could not get resource

I have used proxy settings which are working fine i have downloaded one project it is working fine.I have try all available solutions in google and SO.